# Got error when I use saveToFile to got automatically my attachments on my disk

Tags: vba, attachment

During a PHP project, I "earned" an Access DataBase to work with. I want to save all the attachments (more than 5000) automatically, so I try VBA for that ! Go with the code :

```
Sub debuts_vba()
    
    Dim oRst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim oDb As DAO.Database
    Set oDb = CurrentDb
    Set oRst = oDb.OpenRecordset("stock", dbOpenTable)
    
    Do While Not oRst.EOF
       oRst.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile "C:\fichiers\"
       oRst.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

The loop works, i can access to data but when I want to use SaveToFile on the field, i got the error :

> Method or data member not found

I tried to solve this by my own, and read the "SaveToFile" Doc but I don't see the problem. Is it the wrong type of field ? Do I need another function ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : The new code is :

```
Public Function LoadAttachments() As Long
        Dim oDb As DAO.Database
        Dim oRst As DAO.Recordset2
        Dim rs As DAO.Recordset2
        Dim fld As DAO.Field2
        
        
        
        'Dim oRst As DAO.Recordset
        'Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
        'Dim oDb As DAO.Database
        'Dim fld As Field
        
        Set oDb = CurrentDb
        Set oRst = oDb.OpenRecordset("stock", dbOpenTable)
        Set fld = oRst(21)
        
        
        Do While Not oRst.EOF
            Set rs = fld.Value
            
            Do While Not rs.EOF
        
                strFullPath = "C:\fichiers\img" & "\" & rs("FileName")
                
                'Make sure the file does not exist and save
                rs("FileData").SaveToFile strFullPath
        
                'Next attachment
                rs.MoveNext
            Loop
            rs.Close
            oRst.MoveNext
        Loop
        oRst.Close
        
        rst.Close
        dbs.Close
                
        Set fld = Nothing
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set oRst = Nothing
        Set oDb = Nothing
        
    End Function
```

You can see the comment below to know why i did this changes. However, the type DAO.Recordset2 and DAO.Field2 are not accepted and I don't know why. Do I need to install or activate something ?

EDIT2 : Answer here [dao.recordset2 and dao.field2 not usable. I got compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917465/dao-recordset2-and-dao-field2-not-usable-i-got-compilation-error/65917784#65917784)

Comment: Try without '\': `oRst.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile "C:\fichiers"`

Comment: No change. Always the same error for .SaveToFile

Comment: With more searches, i got 2 changes : I need a loop for various attachments in the field, and I need to add the name of the new file in the path. I edit my first post to show the new code. But the error is the same. In others codes, I see some DAO.Recordset2 instead of DAO.Recordset. I tried to do the same but the type is not accepted. Do i need to install a package or something ? I don't find the info.

Comment: Answer here. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917465/dao-recordset2-and-dao-field2-not-usable-i-got-compilation-error/65917784#65917784