# dao.recordset2 and dao.field2 not usable. I got compilation error

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I just start to work with VBA on Access and I just want to use this type : recordset2 and field2. My aim is to work with attachment. But I got a compilation error when I try to run this :

```
Dim oRst As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset2
Dim fld As DAO.Field2
```

I got alike error

> "undefined user-defined type"

and i don't know why. All the code I read use this types. What have i misunderstood ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a reference to an old DAO library. You need this reference:

*Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library*